# Solving transportation problem by the Network Simplex

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, network-flow

I am trying to solve the following problem using Network Simplex method. But I have questions.

[image]

**My attempt:**

*Basis Matrix$(B)$*

Rows: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Column: (1,3) (1,4) (1,5) (2,3) (2,4) (2,5)

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
     1&1&1&0&0&0  \\
     0&0&0&1&1&1\\
     -1&0&0&-1&0&0\\
     0&-1&0&0&-1&0\\
     0&0&-1&0&0&-1
\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

*Vector of basic variables$(x_B)$*

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
     x_{13}  \\
     x_{14}\\
     x_{15}\\
     x_{23}\\
     x_{24}\\
     x_{25}
\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

**My questions:**

I couldn't be sure where to add the root arc both on the matrix and the graph. I guess I need to add 2 root arcs, but where do I add them?

To solve the problem I need to solve the $B*x_B=b$ equality where $B$ is basis, $x_B$ is the vector of basis variables(consists of the arcs) and $b$ is the capacities. I also couldn't find a way to represent the basis variables.

Comment: Would you see [this](http://iasir.net/AIJRSTEMpapers/AIJRSTEM15-397.pdf) link?